# Why Dhritarastra is not called Vyasa's son?

Tags: mahabharata, vyasa

In Vyasa Mahabharata Pandavas are repeatedly called "the son of Dharma", "the son of Shakra", "twins of Ashwinis".
However, Dhritarastra is always called "son of Vichitravirya".

Pandavas were born while Pandu was alive whereas Dhritarastra was born after his father's death. Still, why Pandavas are referred by their real father whereas Dhritarastra is not?

Is it purely because Vyasa did not want to use his name against his wicked son?!

[*I understand this may be difficult to answer as we need to ask Vyasa himself! But trying to see if I missed some logic/explanations*]

Comment: Well what about Vidur n Pandu. They are also called as sons of Vichitravirya only. As this is what the dharma of niyoga says, the seed doner can't ask for the ownership of the children as it was done for the purpose of giving only, not out of lust.

Answer (score 1):

The proposition that *Pāṇḍu's* sons not being named after their father *Pāṇḍu*, (that *Kuntī* & *Mādrī* beget from various deities) **is wrong**. Those five brothers are rightly called *Pāṇḍavas*, which is derived from the root word *Pāṇḍu*, and hence meaning - "the Sons of *Pāṇḍu*". Just like *Shri Krishna* is called as *Vāsudeva* (वासुदेव), i.e., son of *Vasudeva* (वसुदेव) or, *Kātyāyanī* (कात्यायनी), i.e., daughter of *Rishi Kātyāyana*, similarly the case is  made for the five brothers being called as *Pāṇḍavas*, i.e., the Sons of *Pāṇḍu*.

Now, both *Dhṛtarāṣṭra* & *Pāṇḍu* were begotten by their mothers (*Ambikā* & *Ambālikā*) through *Veda Vyāsa - Krishna Dvaipāyana*, by the ancient (and *dharma* approved)  practice of *[Niyoga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niyoga)*. And thus, legally and in the sense of *Dharma*, both *Dhṛtarāṣṭra* & *Pāṇḍu*, are sons of *Vichitravīrya* only and not of *Veda Vyāsa*, even though *Vyāsa*  maybe their biological father.

> > **Why so? Why *Dhṛtarāṣṭra* (and *Pāṇḍu* ) is not called Vyasa's son, but *Pāṇḍavas* are also referred to by their biological fathers (*devtās*) names?**

As per the [standard rules of *Niyoga*](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7625/which-hindu-text-generally-describes-the-rules-of-niyoga/7628#7628), the progeny conceived, even though not biologically belonging to the husband, is under the eye of *dharma*, very well approved as legal, as defined in the *Manu-Smriti* ([Chapter 9](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/manu/manu09.htm)),  and thus, child born by *Niyoga* is considered as *kshetraja* (क्षेत्रज)  child of the husband-wife.

Further, to mitigate the doubt posed in this question,

**You must see that, you are also missing the fact that not only *Dhṛtarāṣṭra*, but *Pāṇḍu* is also, a son of Vyasa (in the biological sense).** However, the reason for that kind of reference is not in anyway related with assumptions like - " whether if, *Dhṛtarāṣṭra* was evil or not ".

The *Pāṇḍavas* being *also* referenced by their biological father's name, can be thought of in the following two ways:

**1. Poetic & Literary sense**

In the poetic and literary sense. It's an example of Hero glorification / Hero Worship - i.e,  conferring an exalted status to both the *Pāṇḍavas* and thus, their biological fathers (i.e., the *devatās*). The *Pāṇḍavas* are the positive protaganist of the epic. And even if born via *Niyoga*, but, in this case, it's more of a "Divine origin" *Niyoga*, since it involves live *devtaas* as the donors, and thus, they are the direct biological sons of the highly revered and exalted *Vedic* deities. Therefore, since it involves both the process of *Niyoga* and the involvement of sky divinities as donors, and further, the use of a highly potent *mantra* given to *Kuntī* by *Rishi Durvasa*. Since, everything about their birth is divine, thus, the *Pāṇḍavas* are also frequently referred to as by their biological father's name, who are all exalted *devtaas*. In no way, though, it results in the depreciation of the fact, that they were the *dharma* approved progeny begotten by *Kuntī* & *Mādrī* on the [advice and behest of *Pāṇḍu*](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23413/clarification-about-kuntis-statement-on-harlot) himself, and thus rightly, are the sons of the *Pāṇḍu*.
However, *Dhṛtarāṣṭra* is not a positive protaganist of the story and *Pāṇḍu* is more or less, not of significance to the story of *Mahābhārata* after the prologue (*Adi Parva*). Thus, they're not to be exalted in the epic in terms of significance compared to the *Pāṇḍavas*. And hence are unequivocally called as *Vichitravīrya's* sons only.

**2. *Dharma*, ascetism and the influence of *saṃsāric māyā*.**

In case of *Dhṛtarāṣṭra* and *Pāṇḍu*, even though, they are also begotten via *Vyāsa* - who is himself a highly exalted divine person and also a *[Vishnu-aṃśa](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/29371/if-vyasa-is-vishnus-incarnation-will-ashvatthama-whos-the-next-vyasa-will-he)*, but ultimately, he's a sage, and an ascetic and is thought of as someone above the clutches of *saṃsāric māyā*. Thus, *Vyāsa* is  merely performing his *karma* as per *dharma*. Thus, *Vyāsa*, being mostly dispassionate with worldly affairs, is to be taken of as someone, who  is just discharging away his duties and hence in no way identifies with his biological sons (as per the rules of *Niyoga*).

But, *Vyāsa* is an exception. Almost everyone in the material existence have been known to be [influenced by the power of *māyā*](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2053/what-is-maya-and-why-is-it-there), and thus, deities too, are no exceptions. Thus, the deities (the biological fathers), as we can see throughout the *Itihāsa*, seem to be very much connected and concerned with the fate of their human sons, especially in case of *Indra* (*Arjuna*) & *Sūrya* (*Karṇa*), involving the famous ["*Kavacaha-Kuṇḍala*" donation episode](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2248/what-happened-to-karnas-kavach-kundal). Thus, the *Pāṇḍavas* are appropriately referred as, at several instances, in the name of their biological father ( i.e., the *devatās*)  due to active involvement by their respective biological father's in helping and protecting them throughout the *Mahābhārata*.

Comment: Thanks but question wasn't about Niyoga, or legitimacy of the children. Most references in Mahabharata to Pandavas is referring to their real fathers and not Pandu... There are some references saying sons of Pandu but majority is with their real fathers. However it's not the case with Dhritarastra.